# Debugging django with Komodo IDE 7 doesnt break on breakpoints

Tags: django, komodo

I am using Komodo IDE 7 with a Django 1.4 using Python27.

I have been using the remote debugging option of Komodo IDE 7 but it seems to not responed to my breakpoints. If I break in my model decleration/setting.py it does break for the first time but it seems to "disconnect" after the first initialization.

the command I am running the debugger is :

```
set KOMODO_PATH="%ProgramFiles%\ActiveState Komodo IDE 7\lib\support\dbgp\bin"
c:\python27\python %KOMODO_PATH%\pydbgp.py -d localhost:9000 manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that this is a bug in Komodo 7.02. It seems that Django 1.4 uses a multi-threading machanisim which doesnt work well with Komodo.

A bug was filed but for a while there is a work around : using --nothreading while starting manage.py.

However, it seems to effect performance badly !